# ASP.NET + GridView + Dynamic TemplateFields

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that I need to dynamically add TemplateField elements to. My question is, how to I programmatically add dynamic TemplateField elements? I cannot find anything through Google that shows an example of this.

Thank you!

Comment: can you give more explanation by example case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this article](http://www.developer.com/article.php/10915_3609991_2/Dynamic-Template-Columns-in-the-ASPNET-20-GridView-Control.htm) tell you what you need? I think you will have to download the code to see a full example of what you want (link is at the bottom of the article) since he's created some custom template fields.